# Three level nested form in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have 4 models Reports, Category, Question, Answer. My problem is that Report doesn't have associations with category. I want to create nested form like:

```
@report= Report.new
@category = @report.build_category
@quetions = @category.questions.build
@questions.answers.build
```

But without associations reports with categories i cannot do it. I have error like **categories.report_id does not exist** What I'm doing wrong?

**My associations:**

Category => has many => Questions

Questions => has many => Answers

**My db schema:**

```
Reports:
  user_id: integer
  category_id:integer

Category:
  title: string
  slug: string

Question:
  title: string
  category_id: integer

Answer:
  title: string
  question_id: integer
```

Comment: see `@quetions = @category.questions.build`, `@quetions` change to `@questions`

Comment: i have a problem in second line **@category = @report.build_category**. I commented other lines.

Comment: what is association report with category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using the NestedForm Gem (https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form)

```
gem 'nested_form'
```

You need to be doing something like the following in controller:

```
@report= Report.new
@report.build_category
```

Then in view:

```
<%= nested_form_for @report do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :category do |category_form| %>
    <%= category_form.text_field :name %>
    <%= category_form.fields_for :questions do |question_form| %>
      <%= question_form.text_field :question %>
      <%= question_form.fields_for :answers do |answer_form| %>
        <%= answer_form.text_field :answer %>
      <% end %>
      <p><%= question_form.link_to_add "Add a Answer", :answers %></p>
    <% end %>
    <p><%= category_form.link_to_add "Add a Question", :questions %></p>
  <% end %>
```